# sql convert text string from 1 integer (8) to 3 integers (888)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having a little difficulty with the below code - it return the value I am after, but I need the value 3 digits long - i.e. it returns '1' but I need '001' - any help would be gratefully received

```
select convert(varchar(3),(select count(ptMatter) + 1 from lamatter where  
 convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 103)=convert(varchar(10), dateadd, 103)))
```

Comment: Are you trying to repeat the integer three times (question title), or add leading zeros (question body)? Your question is contradictory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select Right('000000' + convert(varchar(3), Result),3)
From yourTable
```

for your exact query:

```
Select Right('000000' + convert(varchar(3), (select count(ptMatter) + 1 from lamatter where convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 103)=convert(varchar(10), dateadd, 103)) ),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your database documentation if the `lpad` function exists. For example, this is the mysql version : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

edit: sorry, didn't saw the tsql tag... Like said in another answer, the `right` function is the way to go, like explained here : [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
DECLARE @i int;
SELECT @i = 1;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@i, 3), ' ', '0')
```