# Integer PadLeft function in T-SQL

Tags: string, t-sql

I have the following table A:

```
id
----
1
2
12
123
1234
```

I need to left-pad the `id` values with zero's:

```
id
----
0001
0002
0012
0123
1234
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

I believe this may be what your looking for:

```
SELECT padded_id = REPLACE(STR(id, 4), SPACE(1), '0') 

FROM tableA
```

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(id, 4), SPACE(1), '0') AS [padded_id]

FROM tableA
```

I haven't tested the syntax on the 2nd example. I'm not sure if that works 100% - it may require some tweaking - but it conveys the general idea of how to obtain your desired output.

**EDIT**

To address concerns listed in the comments...

@pkr298 - Yes STR does only work on numbers... The OP's field is an ID... hence number only.

@Desolator - Of course that won't work... the First parameter is 6 characters long.  You can do something like:

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(id,
(SELECT LEN(MAX(id)) + 4 FROM tableA)), SPACE(1), '0') AS [padded_id] FROM tableA
```

this should theoretically move the goal posts... as the number gets bigger it should ALWAYS work.... regardless if its 1 or 123456789...

So if your max value is 123456... you would see 0000123456 and if your min value is 1 you would see 0000000001

Comment: STR() only works on numbers (or numbers in string fields). This code breaks if you are using it on a varchar field that you assume to have a number but one of the records has bad (non-numeric) data. The RIGHT() function won't break in this case.

Comment: STR() function will not work if the number is greater length (e.g. `STR(123456, 4)` will return `****`

Comment: @Desolator I've added a response and fix to facilitate the scenario you added.

Answer (score 113):

SQL Server now supports the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function starting from version 2012, so:

```
SELECT FORMAT(id, '0000') FROM TableA
```

will do the trick.

If your id or column is in a `varchar` and represents a number you convert first:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT,id), '0000') FROM TableA
```

Comment: Slick and simple, thanks! Given the date of the original question, this should now be the official answer ;)

Comment: If id is a string then you can convert it to integer first -- select format(convert(int,id),'0000')

Comment: Sorry but I downvote because this way is REALLY slow. Took four whole seconds to run over 90 rows, while the accepted answer was instant. This is a very major downside, and the FORMAT should only be used on one or two records, max. Otherwise it's useless due to its very poor performance.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm seeing instantaneous performance using FORMAT with 1000s of rows.

Comment: @JohnnyHK well maybe something with the table design or other db quirks, but still... fact is that for me it was really slow while the other way was fast.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Also had no problems with this, it performs just as fast as other similar functions over 10k+ rows.  Don't think you should be downvoting...

Answer (score 70):

Old post, but maybe this helps someone out:

To complete until it ends up with 4 non-blank characters:

```
SELECT RIGHT ('0000'+COLUMNNAME, 4) FROM TABLENAME;
```

To complete until 10:

```
SELECT RIGHT ('0000000000'+COLUMNNAME, 10) FROM TABLENAME;
```

**In case the column is numeric**, convert it to varchar first with such code:

```
Select RIGHT('0000'+Convert(nvarchar(20), COLUMNNAME), 4)
From TABLENAME
```

And to complete until 10 with a numeric field:

```
SELECT RIGHT ('0000000000'+Convert(nvarchar(20), COLUMNNAME), 10) FROM TABLENAME;
```

Comment: @SilverM-A, there is no utility to add 0s before a number, since they will be ignored anyway (0003 is 3 after all). Probably what you want to accomplish is to cast that number to a string (varchar) and then use the above statement.

Comment: @SilverM-A, if that is the case, just cast it using the "CAST" command like: SELECT RIGHT('0000000000'+CAST(COLUMNNAME AS VARCHAR), 10) FROM TABLENAME; Is that it?

Comment: @MarceloMyara this should be part of the answer, not just a comment. Added now myself.

Comment: Note: this is the most efficient answer, with no fancy functions that might get really slow. Hence I've given it extra bounty.

Answer (score 62):

```
declare @T table(id int)
insert into @T values
(1),
(2),
(12),
(123),
(1234)

select right('0000'+convert(varchar(4), id), 4)
from @T
```

Result

```
----
0001
0002
0012
0123
1234
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',4)+CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(4)),4) FROM [Table A]
```

Answer (score 11):

-- Please look into these.

```
select FORMAT(1, 'd4');
select FORMAT(2, 'd4');
select FORMAT(12, 'd4');
select FORMAT(123, 'd4');
select FORMAT(1234, 'd4');
```

-- I hope these would help you

Comment: Available since SQL Server 2012 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Answer (score 11):

This works for strings, integers and numeric:

`SELECT CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 4 - LEN(id)), id)`

Where `4` is desired length. Works for numbers with more than 4 digits, returns empty string on `NULL` value.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is still interested, I found this article on DATABASE.GUIDE:
[Left Padding in SQL Server – 3 LPAD() Equivalents](https://database.guide/left-padding-in-sql-server-3-lpad-equivalents/)

In short, there are 3 methods mentioned in that article.
Let's say your id=12 and you need it to display as 0012.

**Method 1 – Use the RIGHT() Function**
The first method uses the RIGHT() function to return only the rightmost part of the string, after adding some leading zeros.

`SELECT RIGHT('00' + '12', 4);`

Result:
`0012`

**Method 2 – Use a Combination of RIGHT() and REPLICATE()**
This method is almost the same as the previous method, with the only difference being that I simply replace the three zeros with the REPLICATE() function:

`SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + '12', 4);`

Result:
`0012`

**Method 3 – Use a Combination of REPLACE() and STR()**
This method comes from a completely different angle to the previous methods:

`SELECT REPLACE(STR('12', 4),' ','0');`

Result:
`0012`

Check out the article, there is more in depth analysis with examples.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I normally use when I need to pad a value.

```
SET @PaddedValue = REPLICATE('0', @Length - LEN(@OrigValue)) + CAST(@OrigValue as VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a function to do this, where you can specify the desired output character length:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfLeadingZero]
(
        @String VARCHAR(MAX)
,       @Len INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    SET @String = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',@Len)+@String,@Len)
RETURN @String
END
GO
```

[Example results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SekM8.png)

Answer (score 1):

I needed this in a function on SQL server and adjusted Patrick's answer a bit.

```
declare @dossierId int = 123
declare @padded_id varchar(7)


set @padded_id = REPLACE(
              SPACE(7 - LEN(@dossierId)) + convert(varchar(7), @dossierId), 
              SPACE(1),  
              '0') 

SELECT @dossierId as '@dossierId'
      ,SPACE(LEN(@dossierId)) + convert(varchar(7)
      ,@dossierId) as withSpaces
      ,@padded_id as '@padded_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Function :

```
    Create FUNCTION [dbo].[PadLeft]
      (
        @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Replace NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @Len INT
      )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN 


        DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) 

        SELECT @var = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Text)) , '')


        RETURN   RIGHT(REPLICATE(@Replace,@Len)+ @var, @Len)


    END
```

Example:

```
Select dbo.PadLeft('123456','0',8)
```

Comment: Just a point about standards, I wouldn't bother with the IsNull check, if the value is null then the function should still return null for that value as this is the standard behaviour for the builtin functions. If we convert everything to a non-null value then the caller will no longer be able to use null logic operations that they might otherwise be expecting. (Null in many of my tables means 'not specified' and a default value should be used. `SELECT @var = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Text))`

Answer (score 1):

I created a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnPadLeft](@int int, @Length tinyint)
RETURNS varchar(255) 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strInt varchar(255)

    SET @strInt = CAST(@int as varchar(255))
    RETURN (REPLICATE('0', (@Length - LEN(@strInt))) + @strInt);
END;
```

Use: select dbo.fnPadLeft(123, 10)

Returns: 0000000123

Answer (score 0):

Something fairly ODBC compliant if needed might be the following:

```
select ifnull(repeat('0', 5 - (floor(log10(FIELD_NAME)) + 1)), '')
        + cast (FIELD as varchar(10))
  from TABLE_NAME
```

This bases on the fact that the amount of digits for a base-10 number can be found by the integral component of its log. From this we can subtract it from the desired padding width. Repeat will return `null` for values under 1 so we need `ifnull`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not efficient but helped me in situation where the values (bank cheque numbers and wire transfer ref no.) were stored as varchar where some entries had alpha numeric values with them and I had to pad if length is smaller than 6 chars.

Thought to share if someone comes across same situation

```
declare @minlen int = 6
declare @str varchar(20)

set @str = '123'
select case when len(@str) < @minlen then REPLICATE('0',@minlen-len(@str))+@str else @str end
--Ans: 000123

set @str = '1234'
select case when len(@str) < @minlen then REPLICATE('0',@minlen-len(@str))+@str else @str end
--Ans: 001234

set @str = '123456'
select case when len(@str) < @minlen then REPLICATE('0',@minlen-len(@str))+@str else @str end
--Ans: 123456

set @str = '123456789'
select case when len(@str) < @minlen then REPLICATE('0',@minlen-len(@str))+@str else @str end
--Ans: 123456789

set @str = '123456789'
select case when len(@str) < @minlen then REPLICATE('0',@minlen-len(@str))+@str else @str end
--Ans: 123456789


set @str = 'NEFT 123456789'
select case when len(@str) < @minlen then REPLICATE('0',@minlen-len(@str))+@str else @str end
--Ans: NEFT 123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be

```
    DECLARE @number INTEGER
    DECLARE @length INTEGER
    DECLARE @char   NVARCHAR(10)
    SET @number = 1
    SET @length = 5
    SET @char = '0'

    SELECT FORMAT(@number, replicate(@char, @length))
```

Answer (score -5):

More efficient way is :

```
Select id, LEN(id)
From TableA
Order by 2,1 

The result :
id
----
1
2
12
123
1234
```

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question about padding with zeros?