# convert the numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

First I am converting the value from the table as integer like

```
cast(convert(int, isnull(b.temp,0)) as varchar(500))
```

and then I would like to output values as written below  for example

```
1 as 001
12 as 012
123 as 123

-1 as -001 
-15 as -015
-234 as -234
```

and if length of the integer value is more than 3 then do not display any value or remove it. 
If integer has Minus(-) sign then it is not part of the length
so -001 is consider as length 3

so 001 and -001 is acceptable as length 3

How can I do that?

Comment: Exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540064/how-to-make-padleft-in-sql-server-2008-query

Comment: This solution that you mentioned is good for positive values but not good for negative value

Comment: I don't think this is an *exact* duplicate, but the answer from Bert's link solves this problem. Pad the absolute value as it shows, then stick a negative identifier in front if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no efficient way to do this, but I understand there are situations where this needs to be done. I would probably go about it with something like this turned into a function.

```
DECLARE @myInt as INT
    SET @myInt = -9

DECLARE @padding AS VARCHAR(1)
    SET @padding = '0'
DECLARE @length AS INT
    SET @length = 3 - LEN(ABS(@myInt))

DECLARE @result AS VARCHAR(5)
    SET @result = REPLICATE(@padding, @length) + cast(ABS(@myInt) as VARCHAR(3))
IF @myInt < 0   
        SET @result = '-' + @result

SELECT @result
```

This really should be done in code and not sql.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to 0 pad numbers in a range.  This is one way I do it:

```
select (case when val between 0 and 999
             then right('000'+cast(<col> as varchar(100)), 3)
             when val between -999 and 0
             then '-'+right('000'+cast(abs(<col>) as varchar(100)), 3)
             else ''
        end)
from t
```

Comment: You are right.  It occurs to me that I almost never work with negative numbers that need to be zero padded.  In any case, I was already fixing that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution below works.  Thanks

```
declare @num1 as varchar(50)
set @num1 = '1'
       select (case 
               when @num1 between 0 and 999  then right('000'+cast(@num1 as varchar(100)), 3) 
               when @num1 between -999 and 0  then '-'+right('000'+cast(abs(@num1) as varchar(100)), 3)  
               else ''         
               end) as t
```