# Make column values in a table have equal number of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `DomainDetail` having a column `fieldID`.

It has values like `A1,B22,A567,D7779,B86759` .. i.e. from two characters to max six characters.

I want these values have equal number of characters 
`A000001,B000022,A000567,D07779 and B86759` .

This is how I think I should proceed

- Estimate size of field value = `LEN(fieldID)`
- Insert number of zeros equal to **(6 - number of characters)** .

How can I insert 0's sandwiched inside original value . How can do in SQL ?

Comment: Is it always just one character leading? I mean will you have values like AA1?

Comment: No , first character is ALPHABET , rest are numerals..plz help ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this

```
select 
    left(fieldID, 1) + 
    right('000000' + right(fieldID, len(fieldID) - 1), 5)
from DomainDetail
```

take a look at [**SQL FIDDLE example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d6cf/4)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a problem better solved by business logic, i.e. the layer of code above your database.  Whenever you insert, do the padding in that code - then always use that code/layer to insert into the table.

It seems to be a business logic requirement anyway - "ID must have a maximum 6 characters".  Because a database wouldn't impose such a limit.

(unless you are using stored procedures as your business logic layer? in which case, [PadLeft function in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540064/padleft-function-in-t-sql))

Comment: i don't have access to code implementing business logic , only table...plz help

Comment: help how? make a suggestion, then research how to do development, and write the code for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
stuff(fieldId,2,0,
      LEFT('0000000000000000000000000',
      (select max(LEN(FieldID)) from DomainDetail)

           -LEN(fieldId)))
from DomainDetail
```

If you need a fixed output length just replace inner select (`select max(LEN(FieldID)) from DomainDetail)` with for example `6`
Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be428/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to UPDATE, then use this

```
UPDATE DomainDetail
SET fieldId=
            SUBSTRING(fieldId,1,1)+
            REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(id))+
            SUBSTRING(fieldId,2,LEN(id)-1)
```

If you want to just SELECT without altering the values in the table, then this should work

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(id,1,1)+
       REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(id))+
       SUBSTRING(id,2,LEN(id)-1) 
FROM DomainDetail
```

Hope this helps,

Raj

Answer (score 1):

```
select stuff(fieldid, 2, 0, replicate('0', 6-len(fieldid))) 
from DomainDetail
```