# SQL Server CONVERT int to varchar with padding

Tags: sql-server, varchar, typeconverter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)

I am returning the numeric value of the week given a datetime by using the datepart function in SQL.  I then convert this to a varchar in order to build a string.  My problem is that I need weeks that have a value less than 10 to become "01" instead of "1".  I need this because it is stored that way in another database.

My question is, is there some kind of specification I can give to the CONVERT function in order to force the varchar to be of length 2 instead of length 1?

Here is the statement I have right now:

```
convert(varchar(2),datepart(ww,'2013-1-3 11:00:00.000'))
```

Can I make this return "01" instead of "1"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540064/padleft-function-in-t-sql

Comment: That did it.  I used Martin Smith's response using the RIGHT function.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it in:

```
right('0' + convert(...), 2)
```

Alternatively:

```
right(100 + datepart(ww, ...), 2)
```

Comment: Yeah that works.  You can also use RTRIM instead of CONVERT, you can just do:  right('0'+rtrim(datepart(ww,'2013-4-20 11:00:00.000')), 2)