# How to cast a number to string with 0 prefix in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server, if I have a number `n`, and `n>=0 and n<=100`, how to cast it into a string with sql?

```
1 => '01'
2 => '02'
...
10 => '10'
99 => '99'
```

It is something like printf.

```
printf ('%2d", n);
```

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540064/padleft-function-in-t-sql

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So long as n is strictly *less* than 100, you can use

```
  RIGHT(100+n,2)
```

In SQL Server 2012, you can also use FORMAT, and the following will work and also give you '100' for 100.

```
  FORMAT(n,'00','en-US')
```

Answer (score 2):

`%2d` needs to translated to `2 digit` format in sql server

Try this

```
Declare @val int
set @val=1
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(@val AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Result :-

```
01
```

In order to check for numbers between `0 to 100` use `case` statement

```
SELECT  case when @val>0 and @val<100 then 
               RIGHT('0' + CAST(@val AS VARCHAR), 2)
               else 
               NULL
               END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select RIGHT('00'+ convert(varchar, @val), 3)
```

Comment: I think you need `2` instead of `3` for your last parameter (if you want `01` not `001`). Otherwise this seems the most generic and readable solution to me. Can also be used for computed persisted columns (while, for some reason, FORMAT is considered non-deterministic by SQL server)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach (not sure how you want to handle numbers greater than 99):

```
DECLARE @numbers AS TABLE(Val INT)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(10)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(11)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(98)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(99)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES(100)
SELECT REPLACE(STR(Val, 2), ' ', '0') FROM @numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT FORMAT(ColumnName,'0000') FROM TableName
```

Eg:

```
SELECT FORMAT(50,'0000')
```

Output: `0050`

Answer (score 1):

you can use LPAD function of sql

**Try this**

```
SELECT LPAD(n, 2, 0);

Result
01
02
....
10
```

Explanation : The LPAD function Left-pad the string with 3rd parameter( i.e 0 in given example) up to length given in 2nd parameter ( i.e 2 in given example)

**more example**

```
SELECT LPAD('hello', 10, '*');
Result :  *****hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE(n INT)
INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES(1),(3),(5),(9),(10),(50),(99),(100)

Select Case When n<10 Then '0'+Cast(n as varchar(10)) Else Cast(n as varchar(10)) End From @table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(id, 4), SPACE(1), '0') AS YY FROM tableA
```

This would smart way to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(2, '0#')       .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with 2 integers, e.g. month numbers:

SELECT RIGHT(CAST(MONTH(GETDATE())+100 AS VARCHAR(3)),2)

"MONTH(GETDATE())" being any expression.