# how to make a left space in a nchar(2) word?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select a month from a column `CMonth` but I want to preview it as :- `01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12.` 
I wrote this code but it preview it as :-
`10 , 20 , 30 , 40 , 50 , 60 .... 10,11,12`

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(CAST(CMonth AS NCHAR(2)),' ','0'))) 
from tablename
```

Comment: Can you show the sample data of your table?

Comment: aha it is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 without zeros @SankarRaj

Comment: it got marked as duplicate.. anyway you can use the following code.. 
SELECT  CASE WHEN CMonth <10 THEN '0'+CAST(CMonth as  VARCHAR(10)) 
            ELSE CAST(CMonth as VARCHAR(10)) END AS CMonth from tablename

Comment: I think i found it thanks :)

Comment: @BishoyEzzat: Look at your question, the duplicate is linked: _"This question already has an answer here:
[PadLeft function in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540064/padleft-function-in-t-sql)"_

Comment: yes I did .. thanks :)