# Leading 0 on int Column problem SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an issue where I am trying to add a leading 0 to run an output.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(t.trans_time) = 5 
            THEN CONCAT(0, [trans_time])
            ELSE T.[trans_time] 
     END AS [TransactionTime]

     ,RIGHT(CONCAT(0,trans_time),6) AS trans_time

    ,LEN(T.trans_Time)

    ,t.trans_time
```

[image]

Why does the case statement not return the leading 0 whereas using:

```
,RIGHT(CONCAT(0,trans_time),6) AS trans_time
```

Works no problem.

Comment: Format output in the code which run sql query. Programming languages are much better tool for this then SQL. Sql wasn't designed for pretty output.

Comment: The case can only return one datatype, so make sure that all cases return varchar. Just convert the ELSE to varchar and it should work

Comment: Maybe this can help you also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540064/padleft-function-in-t-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case expression return only one type, whereas  `concat()` would return different type & i am assuming `trans_time` has `INT` type.

So, you would need to do type conversations :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LEN(t.trans_time) = 5 
             THEN CONCAT(0, [trans_time])
             ELSE CAST(T.[trans_time]  AS VARCHAR(255))
         END) AS [TransactionTime],
. . .
```

Comment: So this would mean it will implicitly convert the concatenated values to a Varchar()

Comment: Also the brackets around the CASE statement don't make a difference

Comment: @MarkTimson. . . There is no brackets, there is two parenthesis one is opening `(` & other is closing `)` to make the code clear & readable.

Comment: Though this answers the question, I still wonder if the `format` function would not be better suited for this job

Comment: @GuidoG Both work just as well as eachother as I can see Thanks for your input. Up voting your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to use the format function, wich is available from sql server 2012.
It not only makes the code more readable but will also perform better.

```
declare @t table (id int)
insert into @t values (90113), (90204), (90207), (90235), (90302), (90318), (90324)

select format(id, '000000') as TransactionTime from @t
```

this will return

```
TransactionTime 
---------------
090113  
090204  
090207  
090235  
090302  
090318  
090324
```