# Formation of 20 Character string concatenating by five fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i want to Form a String of length 20 character with preceding zero as per rule as given below.

my table looks like:-

[image]

The maximum number of 0 preceed in these five field are
for
 `CLASS: 4 VENDOR : 5 STYLE : 4 COLOR: 3 SIZE: 4`

Output Table looks like:-

[image]

Can we do this with sql query.
Please help.

The Output should looks like:-

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540064/integer-padleft-function-in-t-sql

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000'  + ISNULL(CAST(CLASS  AS VARCHAR(4)), '') , 4)
    +  RIGHT('00000' + ISNULL(CAST(VENDOR AS VARCHAR(5)), '') , 5)
    +  RIGHT('0000'  + ISNULL(CAST(STYLE  AS VARCHAR(4)), '') , 4)
    +  RIGHT('000'   + ISNULL(CAST(COLOR  AS VARCHAR(3)), '') , 3)
    +  RIGHT('0000'  + ISNULL(CAST(SIZE   AS VARCHAR(4)), '') , 4)
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and later versions, you can also make use of the [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function

```
SELECT CONCAT (
                RIGHT(CONCAT ( '0000'  , CLASS)  , 4)
            ,   RIGHT(CONCAT ( '00000' , VENDOR) , 5)
            ,   RIGHT(CONCAT ( '0000'  , STYLE)  , 4)
            ,   RIGHT(CONCAT ( '000'   , COLOR)  , 3)
            ,   RIGHT(CONCAT ( '0000'  , SIZE)   , 4)
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `format()` function

```
select format(CLASS,'0000') as CLASS,
       format(VENDOR,'00000') as VENDOR,
       format(STYLE,'0000') as STYLE,
       format(COLOR,'000') as COLOR,
       format(SIZE,'0000') as SIZE
from mytable
```

If you want to show 00000 instead of nulls then :

```
select format(coalesce(CLASS,0),'0000') as CLASS,
       format(coalesce(VENDOR,0),'00000') as VENDOR,
       format(coalesce(STYLE,0),'0000') as STYLE,
       format(coalesce(COLOR,0),'000') as COLOR,
       format(coalesce(SIZE,0),'0000') as SIZE
from mytable
```

So the String of length 20 characters with preceding zero could be :

```
select format(coalesce(CLASS,0),'0000') +
       format(coalesce(VENDOR,0),'00000') +
       format(coalesce(STYLE,0),'0000') +
       format(coalesce(COLOR,0),'000') +
       format(coalesce(SIZE,0),'0000') as CONCATENAD
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/HPcaDxdJ)

Comment: Using FORMAT() function without handling the possible null values in the data will return incorrect string.