# How to mask credits card in sql?

Tags: sql, performance

I need to do an update on a table that has over 1 million records to mask the credit cards.

I have to keep the last 4 digits and the rest should become X's.

I come up with this so far

```
BEGIN TRAN
-- SQL update in batches of 10,000
WHILE (2 > 1)
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE TOP ( 10000 ) tblMyTable
    SET creditCardNumber = 'XXXXXX' + RIGHT(creditCardNumber, 4)
   WHERE myDate < '2010-Feb-02'

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
         BREAK
      END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    -- 1 second delay
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  END -- WHILE
GO
ROLLBACK
```

The problem with this though is there are records in the database that are obviously fake credit cards and may not even have 4 digits. Basically what I need to update this to is this add the same number of X's and keep the last 4 digits. If there are less than 4 digits then add some more X's.

Example

```
1242 would turn into XXXXXX1242
12 would turn into   XXXXXXXX12 
1234567890 would turn into  XXXXXX7890
```

Comment: Send the table over to me, and I'll gladly help you out :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen LOL. I think we can find plenty of russian sites that would help for free!

Comment: wonder if you can use substring and achieve that. for example create maximum number of 'xxxx' string. and than use length and substring add to rihgt(creditcardnumber, 4). what you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @xx VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @length INT

SET @length = 17
SET @xx = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

UPDATE TOP ( 10000 ) tblMyTable 
    SET creditCardNumber = SUBSTRING(@xx, 0, @length - len(RIGHT(creditCardNumber, 4))) + RIGHT(creditCardNumber, 4) 
   WHERE myDate < '2010-Feb-02'
```

see if this solves it.

Answer (score 4):

If the only problem is some numbers are less than four characters, left pad it?

see [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)

for an explanation of how

right('XXXXXXXXXXXX'+ @str, @n)

works.

Comment: I think this will be my only problem. I am still not sure if it is in a end-less loop. I ran it and it seemed to go over the number of rows I was told there would be. I am actually unsure how IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
gets satisfied to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    stuff(account_no,1,len(account_no)-4,REPLICATE('X', LEN(account_no)-4)),
    account_no,
    stuff(routing_no,1,len(routing_no)-3,REPLICATE('X', LEN(routing_no)-3)),
    routing_no
from dbo.PAYER_BANK_DETAIL
```