# How to properly Trim values inside SQL Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)

Im having some trouble with syntax trimming with an sql statement. Here is my sql statement that I am failing miserably at :

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PID = TRIM([PID] & Right("00000000" & TRIM ([PID]),8) & ",END"), FROM dbo.MDRMASTER WHERE PARENTPID = @PARENTPID",con);
```

As you can see, Ive been experimenting all over the place, but before I butchered my SQL Statement, the values I returned this :

```
 123456123456123456
```

I want to return this :

```
 00123456,00123456,00123456,END
```

So what is the proper syntax to separate values by commas, add a word on the end of the statement, and to sort the values into a certain format. For example the numbers should all be 8 digits. Whether the return is 00000123 or 01234567. Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length

Comment: What is the format and type of PID itself?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL that would work for this is

```
DECLARE @pidList VARCHAR(2000);

SELECT @pidList = COALESCE(@pidList + ',', '') + REPLICATE('0', 8 - DATALENGTH(MDRMASTER.PID)) + MDRMASTER.PID
FROM dbo.MDRMASTER
WHERE MDRMASTER.PARENTPID = @PARENTPID;

SELECT @pidList + ',END' AS PID;
```

Unfortunately I can't test passing this all in one string through a SqlCommand() object, but I don't see why it wouldn't work if you put the commands, separated by semi-colons into one string.