# Select query with length issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)

I have the customer table where the customerID is of length:10
but there are few customer where the length is 3 or 5

```
ex: 
3445
34
789
7800
```

but the output should be like the following, I need to prefix zero here if length is less than 10

```
0000003445
0000000034
0000000789
0000007800
```

Script to get this data is:

```
select customerID from customer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

Since you are using sql server 2008, you could use replicate function to add zeros to the value..

```
Select ltrim(right(replicate(0,10) + <column>,10)) 
from your_table
```

Comment: this will avoid necessity of counting zeros, will be slower though.

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper: slowness due to replicate is negligible ..  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this way...

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000' + RTRIM('3445'), 10)
```

In your case,

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000' + RTRIM(customerID), 10) AS New_CustomerID
FROM Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000'+`customerID`, 10) FROM `customer`
```