# How to check value of a VARCHAR(50) columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, .net, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am a novice user to sql and need help buidling this stored proc I am working on. One of the values that I pass through my stored proc is ClassCodeGroup and sometimes its less than 10. How do I check if its less than 10 in sql ? 
If its less than 10 (1-9) then I want to add a leading 0 to it which I am thinking should be something like this.

```
select RIGHT('0' + convert (varchar(50), @ClassCodeGroup),2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length

Comment: The answer here is: **Don't store numeric data in varchar columns!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this would be

```
select RIGHT(CAST(,1000+@ClassCodeGroup AS char(8)),2)
```

This way you will not have to check the lenght of `@ClassCodeGroup`, since you simply convert a number with leading zeros and regard only the last two digits. Just changed it to CAST, since I was not sure about the CONVERT syntax ...

Comment: Could you tell me what is ,1000+@ClassCodeGroup for ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ I add 1000 (or another large number) with at least 2 zeros to it (100 would actually be enough), so I will always end up with a number that has either leading zeros or the 2 digit number of `@ClassCodeGroup` in it. It even works when `@ClassCodeGroup` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

> I am a novice user to sql and need help buidling this stored proc 
>   How do I check if its less than 10 in sql

You could use [`IF .. THEN .. ELSE .. END IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) in stored procedure and triggers:

```
IF @ClassCodeGroup < 10
THEN
  -- do something
ELSE
  -- do other thing
END IF;
```

---

> If its less than 10 (1-9) then I want to add a leading 0

However, for *that* specific case, MySQL provide the [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function to do that exactly:

```
SELECT LPAD(@ClassCodeGroup, 2, '0')
```

Please note than would truncate values greater than 99.

---

Finally, and to go back to your initial question, you could use the [*functional* `IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT IF(@ClassCodeGroup>10, 
          @ClassCodeGroup, 
          CONCAT('0',@ClassCodeGroup)
         )
```

Here I used the [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in order to prepend values less than 10 with a leading '0'. note with this version, values greater or equal to 10 are left *unchanged*.