# Getting Year and Month from SQL

Tags: sql-server

I get the Year and Month using this Query given below

```
select CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR )+'0'+CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
```

But for this Month is printing Correctly but for 10 month its printing 010 can any one help on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length

Comment: The best way to get this should be SQL format using 

    `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 112)`

You can take substring and remove the last 2 digits 

    `SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 112), 0,7)`

Comment: I would say this is not duplicate because user is not requesting for the same, but we can suggest the better answer and optimize the query.

Comment: @Murtaza or just simply `CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112)`

Comment: yes @GarethD - That is also possible (i missed out that...) `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(), 112)` this code will give the best result in efficient way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to eliminate the extraneous digit is with the RIGHT function:

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2);
```