# Reg: Auto incrementing a value in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I got a value in a field called it (EmployeeDetailKey - varchar(10)) with sequential values such as

> 00001, 00002, 00003....

It is in a table Employeedetail. When ever a new Employee detail has to be inserted I have to get the max(EmployeeDetailKey) and increment by 1 and store it back. If I have 10 employeedetail records that need to be inserted then the same procedure has to follow.

> If the max(EmployeeDetailKey) = 00003 then after inserting 10 records
>   it has to be 00013. Later on after inserting let us say 100 records it has to
>   be 00113.

How can I do it in the form of MS-SQL statement.

**Please note the column cannot be identity type.**

Comment: are gaps allowed/permitted? what have to happen when (not 'if', 'when') a row will be deleted? which version of sql server? are you allowed to change the column type and use numeric data types?

Comment: yes gaps are allowed. For example when employee leaves the organization that employee detail is deleted but when the employee details need to be added it has to follow a sequence. The version i have is SQL-Server 2008.

Comment: What if the last added employee leaves the organization? A simple "+1" approach would use the same number once again... Very dangerous...

Comment: what's the use of a sequence then? with gaps and deletion it has no added value. why not just use a `GUID` or any other random ID that's easier to manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a solution without changing the table structure, then:

1. Cast your zero-padded string value to int. This is easy in SQl server, as it will easily convert such strings to numbers:

   `SELECT CAST('00003' AS int)`

   This will return integer value of 3.
2. Find MAX()

   Just perform `MAX()` on column you've just converted to string, like...

   `SELECT MAX(CAST(mycolumn AS int)) FROM mytable`

   Actually, you don't have to do a conversion, as SQL server will sort the values correctly in original string representation.
3. Increment

   This is easy, since you now have the integer value, so...

   `SELECT MAX(CAST(mycolumn AS int)) + 1 FROM mytable`
4. Convert it back to zero-padded string

   SQL Server 2008 is a bit tricky to tame here, since left-padding is not his speciality. However, starting from in SQL Server 2012, there is a FORMAT function available, so, you can use...

   `SELECT FORMAT(MAX(CAST(mycolumn AS int)) + 1, '00000') FROM mytable`

   If you have only SQL Server 2005 or 2008 available, you can use `REPLICATE()` combined with `LEN()` to get what you need (disclaimer: UGLY CODE):

   `SELECT REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(MAX(CAST(mycolumn AS int)) + 1)) + CAST((MAX(CAST(mycolumn AS int)) + 1) AS nvarchar(5)) FROM mytable`

   **EDIT** As Luaan hinted, you can use another padding option (shorter and more readable code):

   `SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(MAX(CAST(mycolumn AS int) + 1) as nvarchar(5)), 5) FROM mytable`

Comment: There's a nicer way on pre-2012 - `right('00000' + value, 5)`. I'm not aware of any performance implications (it's never been a bottleneck for me), but we're doing serializable updates for the autoincrement anyway, so...

Comment: @Luaan: great, I've included that solution in the answer

Answer (score 4):

Just add an identity column to your table.  I would suggest something like:

```
IntEmployeeDetailKey int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
. . .
```

Then add a computed column:

```
EmployeeDetailKey as (right(('00000' + cast(IntEmployeeDetailKey as varchar(10)), 5)
```

Then SQL Server will do the incrementing automatically.  And you can get the value out as a zero-padded string.

Comment: The column cannot be identity type. That is a constraint I have :(.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is mandatory that `EmployeeDetailKey` must have this format.

I'll suggest you to substitute the datatype from `varchar(10)` to `IDENTITY`.

`IDENTITY` is a sort of special data type that gets automatically incremented by SQL Server each time you insert a row in the parent table. You can learn more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

If you need to present it with leading zeroes you can always select it like this (liberally adapted from here: [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)):

```
SELECT right('00000'+ rtrim(EmployeeDetailKey), 5) FROM YourTable
```