# SQL convert quarter date number to string padding 0s as prefix for numbers < 10

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to convert monthly_dates to quarter, but I'd like to path single digit numbers with 0s.
I.e., 
monthly_date = '2015-01-01'
In the SQL query I do:
QUARTER(monthly_date)*3-2 AS varchar
but that gives me '1' instead of '01'

Is there a way to make it give me '01', '04', '07' and '10'?

Comment: Yes, but that depends on the SQL engine you use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient T-SQL way to pad a varchar on the left to a certain length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length)

Comment: @juergend thanks.  I use https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/PDF/HP_Vertica_7.0.x_SQL_Reference_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Can you have quarter number bigger than 4?

Anyhow... you can pad numbers the way you want (be sure to check **SQL Reference Manual > SQL Functions > Formatting Functions**).

For example:

```
SQL> select to_char( 4 , '09' ) ;
 to_char 
---------
   04
SQL> select to_char( 12 , '09' ) ;
 to_char 
---------
   12
```

Answer (score -1):

I admit, this is a brute force method but I have used it in the past.
Given these 4 variables, I can calculate the StartCalendarId with padded 0's

```
Declare @StartDate date
Declare @StartYear int
Declare @StartMonth int
Declare @StartDay int

Set @StartYear = Year(@StartDate)
Set @StartMonth = Month(@StartDate)
Set @StartDay = Day(@StartDate)

Set @StartCalendarId =
(CONVERT([int],
    (((CONVERT([varchar](4),@StartYear)+
    case when len(@StartMonth)=(1) then '0' else '' end)+
    CONVERT([varchar](2),@StartMonth))+
    case when len(@StartDay)=(1) then '0' else '' end)
    +CONVERT([varchar](2),@StartDay))
)
```

Comment: This is not SQL Server

Comment: Actually, it is exact code in one of my SQL stored procedures.   The idea is that given a date, you can express the date with padded zeroes in integer form.

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't work with Vertica; which is the database tagged in the question.