# How to pad a number with zero?

Tags: sql-server

A table was built, however, there is one column for the District School. This field should be in a 0000 format, however when the table was built, it dropped the leading zeros, so, if a District School number was 0001, it came in as 1, same as if the DS number was 0052, it came in as 52, but I need to alter that column so that all values are reflected as 0000. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Numbers have no leading zeroes. 52 is the same as 0052. If you want the field to have leading zeroes it should be a `varchar`. Why store the 0s though and not just format the number when displaying it?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121864/most-efficient-t-sql-way-to-pad-a-varchar-on-the-left-to-a-certain-length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000'+ISNULL(field,''),4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[strCeros]
(
    @numero     INT,
    @cifras     TINYINT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR 
(
    25
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(25)
    IF @cifras > 25
        SET @cifras = 25
    
    SET @str = RIGHT(
            REPLICATE('0', @cifras) + CAST(@numero AS NVARCHAR(25)),
            @cifras
        )
    
    RETURN @str
END
GO

SELECT dbo.strCeros(99, 4) padZeros
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id , REPLICATE('0', 4 - len( cast(id as nvarchar) ) ) + cast(id as nvarchar)
from (
        select 1 id
        union
        select 5 id
        union
        select 8 id
        union
        select 19 id
        union
        select 33 id
        union
        select 52 id
    ) dts
```